# PHP code, breaking somewhere in this flow. Can't figure out where the error is

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

I've been working on this for 2 days straight with no progress. Basically I'm pulling a list of parts determined by the year, make, and model of a car. The database was written by someone else, so piecing the mess they made together has turned out to be quite a task. So. It's pulling multiple autoparts, from multiple tables, and grouping them together, first by car, then by individual parts with part No. Price, Description, etc. Even using the original code that the site was designed with, breaks at this point. The ajax calls for the year, make, and model all work, it's when I reach these lines of code, that it breaks.

`$vid` is defined by the `yearID` from the `modelyear` table

```
function loadDetails($vid)
{
    $modelYearDetails = "
        SELECT Model,YETD.yearID,startYear,endYear,bodyType,engine,Drivetrain,Transmissions,wheelbase
        FROM year_engine_tran_drive YETD
        LEFT JOIN wheelbase W ON YETD.wheelbaseID = W.wheelbaseID
        LEFT JOIN engines E ON YETD.engineID = E.idengines
        LEFT JOIN transmissions T ON YETD.transmissionID = T.idTransmissions
        LEFT JOIN drivetrains D ON YETD.driveTrainID = D.idDrivetrains
        LEFT JOIN bodytype BT ON YETD.bodyTypeID = BT.idbodyType
        LEFT JOIN modelyear MY ON YETD.yearID = MY.VID
        LEFT JOIN model M ON MY.idModel = M.idModel
        WHERE yearID IN (".$vid.")";

    $stmt = $this->dbConnect->getDBHandle()->prepare($modelYearDetails);
    $stmt->execute();
    $cnt = 0;

    foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row)
    {
        $model      = $row['Model'];
        $yearID     = $row['yearID'];
        $startYear  = $row['startYear'];
        $endYear    = $row['endYear'];
        $name       = $row['bodyType'];
        $engine     = $row['engine'];
        $driveTrain = $row['Drivetrain'];
        $transmission = $row['Transmissions'];
        $wheelbase  = $row['wheelbase'];
        $cab    = $row['cab'];
        $bed    = $row['bed'];

        echo "<header id=".$yearID.">";
        echo "<a href='#".$yearID."'>";
        echo "<div>".$model." ".$startYear."-".$endYear."</div>";
        echo "<ul>";
        echo "<li><div class='carPart'>Engine:</div>        <div class='carValue'>".$engine."</div></li>";
        echo "<li><div class='carPart'>Drivetrain:</div>    <div class='carValue'>".$driveTrain."</div></li>";
        echo "<li><div class='carPart'>Transmission:</div>  <div class='carValue'>".$transmission."</div></li>";
        echo "</ul>";
        echo "</a>";
        echo "<div style='clear:both;'></div>";
        echo "</header>";
```

Now. This is from an include file, so I'm not getting the MySQL error when it crashes. Perhaps the code is fine, but something is breaking it somewhere. It's not spitting out an error, or anything. It's just leaving the div blank. I know it's a lot of code to go through, but the file is somewhere around 560 lines long, and I wasn't about to post all that. TY in advance for any help that might be provided. Even tips on how to clean this up would be great.

Comment: Use a try catch block http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php Also if you are on PDO use prepared statements don`t concateneate directly into the query.

Comment: You're gonna have to log errors and check those, too many failure points to make a guess here.

Comment: If there is no error, consider maybe the query is returning no results?

Comment: try running the query manually against your database and see what results you get

Comment: I used phpMyadmin, & copy/pasted the code in SQL. I got a few results some times, & no errors. A lot of the entries would return no results. I might just have to tell my client that this database, & the code provided are written in such a way, that it's broken. I know they have parts for a specfic vehicle, yet the query shows up empty. And for Mihai, I agree, this is terrible coding practice. I didn't write this code, I'm just trying to clean up someone else's garbage. I already went through another one of there files, and reduced it from 670 lines of code to 47, and obtained the same result.